# Downloading Photo from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, storage

I have tried really every method i found and it stil didnt worked so I am writing here

I am trying to download photo from Firebase storage from my folder "images" where will be file with same name as current Authorized user ID.  Only problem here is that it doesnt work. Only background of  object is shown (I am changing photo on ShapableImageView)

Bellow I add code, logs and photo  from app .

Code :

```
  private void downloadProfile() {

    User localUser = new User("","","0","","",0,0,0);
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        database_ref.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    localUser.name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    localUser.mail = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                    localUser.age = snapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
                    localUser.phone = snapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    localUser.address = snapshot.child("address").getValue().toString();
                    localUser.login_method = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("login_method").getValue().toString());
                    localUser.playlist_amount = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("playlist_amount").getValue().toString());
                    localUser.fav_song_amount = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("fav_song_amount").getValue().toString());

                    profile_email.setText(localUser.mail);
                    profile_name.setText( localUser.name);
                    age_edit_t.setText(localUser.age);
                    phone_edit_t.setText(localUser.phone);
                    address_edit_t.setText(localUser.address);

                    //  Image download
                    storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://altas-notas.appspot.com");

                    storageReference.child("images/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            profile_img.setImageURI(uri);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                        }
                    });

               
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logs : https://pastebin.com/F0hCxZsv

[image: Click for Photo]

[image]

No matter how i try to download and set photo its transparent or  default.

If it matters , I also add part of code that change image :

```
    private void startGallery() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super method removed
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1000) {
             returnUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
            try {
                bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), returnUri);
                profile_img.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Upload image

            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            storageReference.child("images/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).putFile(returnUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        System.out.println("Upload image is successful!");

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Upload image failed!");

                    }
                }
            });
            //Upload rest of information
            updateProfile();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your code:

```java
storageReference.child("images/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg")
```

You don't need the `.jpg`. Try it like this:

```java
storageReference.child("images/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
```

Comment: I tried this also before and it idnt worked.  I forgot to close it but I found Piccasso and Glide  which helped me load photo. I prefer Glide for high speed loading